# Garantir que objeto genérico passado como parâmetro seja subclasse de uma classe abstrata

Tags: java, parâmetros, genéricos, classes-abstratas

*Primeiramente gostaria de dizer que a minha dúvida não é especificamente sobre **"verificar que um objeto genérico passado como parâmetro seja subclasse de uma classe abstrata."**, mas é que eu não consegui escolher um título melhor. Se vocês acharem uma frase melhor, sintam-se livres pra mudar.*

Bem, a minha situação é essa, eu tenho uma interface `GerenciarClientes`,que especifica operações para gerenciar clientes, uma classe abstrata `AbstractCliente` que contém parâmetros *default* que toda subclasse dela deve ter, e uma classe abstrata `AbstractGerenciadorClientes` que implementa `GerenciarClientes` e possui um método abstrato:

**GerenciarClientes**:

```
public interface GerenciarClientes{

    void adicionar(Object cliente);
    void remover(Object cliente);
    void editar(Object cliente);
}
```

**AbstractCliente**:

```
public abstract class AbstractCliente{

    protected int codigo;

    public AbstractClient(int codigo){
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

**AbstractGerenciador**:

```
public class AbstractGerenciador implements GerenciarClientes{

    /* Construtor */

    @Override
    void adicionar(Object cliente);

    @Override
    void remover(Object cliente);

    @Override
    void editar(Object cliente);

    protected abstract boolean verificaDadosCliente(Object cliente);
}
```

**O meu problema é o seguinte:** Quando eu crio a classe `MeuGerenciador`, que extende `AbstractGerenciadorCliente` eu sou obrigado a implementar o método `verificaDadosCliente(Object cliente)` e passar um objeto como parâmetro. Nesse caso, eu gostaria que o objeto fosse uma subclasse de `AbstractCliente` ( suponha que o nome da subclasse seja `MeuCliente`). Na classe `AbstractCliente` eu cheguei a mudar o parâmetro do método abstrato para `Class<? extends AbstractCliente> cliente`, mas o problema é que quando eu faço isso, eu não consigo realizar o typeCast para a classe `MeuCliente`

```
protected abstract boolean verificaDadosCliente(Class< ? extends AbstractCliente>  cliente){

    MeuCliente c = (MeuCliente) cliente; // ERRO
}
```

1. Como posso solucionar esse erro?
2. Caso o ideal seja manter a assinatura original (passando `Object
   cliente`) como eu posso verificar que o objeto extende
   `AbstractCliente`?
3. Toda vez que eu der *override* no método abstrato eu tenho que fazer o typeCast dentro do método? Ou tem alguma forma de fazer isso automaticamente?

Comment: Declarar o método como `verificaDadosCliente(AbstractCliente cliente)` não resolve? Daí você o chama passando o objeto do tipo `MeuCliente` como parâmetro, o que vai funcionar porque ele também é um `AbstractCliente`.

Comment: @Piovezan O problema é que `MeuCliente` pode possuir métodos próprios, portanto, não seria possível acessá-los usando `AbstractCliente`

Comment: @regmoraes mas se você PRECISA dos métodos em ``MeuCliente``, não adianta tentar fazer genérico assim. Você teria que usar ``verificaDadosCliente(MeuCliente cliente)``, já que não é qualquer instância de ``AbstractCliente`` que vai funcionar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer *cast* no cenário em que citou. Java dá suporte a tipos genéricos desde a versão 5, então você pode dizer que `verificaDadosCliente` espera sempre um tipo que herde de `AbstractCliente`, sendo que o tipo concreto será informado na implementação concreta de `AbstractGerenciador`.

Então, aparentemente, você pode fazer o que deseja de duas maneiras:

- dizer nas subclasses de `AbstractGerenciador` qual é o tipo concreto esperado, então poderá usar algo assim:

```java
public abstract class AbstractGerenciador<E extends AbstractCliente> implements GerenciarClientes {

    // outros métodos

    protected abstract boolean verificaDadosCliente(final E cliente);

}

public class MeuGerenciador extends AbstractGerenciador<MeuCliente> {

    @Override
    protected boolean verificaDadosCliente(final MeuCliente cliente) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

- mudar a assinatura de `verificaDadosCliente` para algo como isto:

```java
protected abstract <E extends AbstractCliente> boolean verificaDadosCliente(final E cliente);
```

Nesta alternativa, a implementação na classe filha ficará parecida com isto:

```java
@Override
protected <T extends AbstractCliente> boolean verificaDadosCliente(final T cliente) {
    final Class<?> providedType = cliente.getClass();
    final Class<MeuCliente> expectedType = MeuCliente.class;
    if (!expectedType.isAssignableFrom(providedType)) {
        final String message = "Tipo esperado não corresponde ao informado. Esperado '%s', encontrado '%s'.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(message, expectedType.getName(), providedType.getName()));
    }

    final MeuCliente obj = expectedType.cast(cliente);

    final boolean result = false;

    // faz o que precisa na verificação

    return result;
}
```

Ao meu ver, a melhor forma de você garantir isto é alterando a sua classe `AbstractGerenciador` para esperar sempre um tipo que herde de `AbstractCliente`, pois provavelmente o tipo esperado em `adicionar`, `remover` e `editar` será também o mesmo.

Uma possível versão final de seus objetos se pareceria com isto:

- *interface* `GerenciarClientes`:

```java
public interface GerenciarClientes<E extends AbstractCliente> {

    void adicionar(final E cliente);

    void remover(final E cliente);

    void editar(final E cliente);

}
```

- classe abstrata `AbstractGerenciador`:

```java
public abstract class AbstractGerenciador<E extends AbstractCliente> implements GerenciarClientes<E> {

    @Override
    public void adicionar(final E cliente) { }

    @Override
    public void remover(final E cliente) { }

    @Override
    public void editar(final E cliente) { }

    protected abstract boolean verificaDadosCliente(final E cliente);

}
```

- um cliente concreto(`MeuCliente`):

```java
public class MeuCliente extends AbstractCliente {

    public MeuCliente() {
        super(1);
    }

}
```

- um gerenciador concreto(`MeuGerenciador`):

```java
public class MeuGerenciador extends AbstractGerenciador<MeuCliente> {

    @Override
    protected boolean verificaDadosCliente(final MeuCliente cliente) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Com isto você não precisa verificar se o tipo é realmente o que espera, mesmo que a referência seja para `AbstractGerenciador`, já que ao instanciar `MeuGerenciador` você irá falar ao compilador o tipo esperado no genérico, algo assim:

```java
AbstractGerenciador<MeuCliente> gerenciador = new MeuGerenciador();
```

Caso a referência seja para o tipo concreto você não irá informar o tipo concreto de `AbstractCliente`, bastando ficar assim:

```java
MeuGerenciador gerenciador = new MeuGerenciador();
```

Em ambos será garantido que o tipo esperado em `verificaDadosCliente` `MeuCliente`.

Um bom guia para brincar com genéricos em java você encontra no [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) de genéricos da própria Oracle.

Comment: Perfeito! Mas ainda tem um pequeno "problema". Essas classes fazem parte de um pequeno framework, então acho que a API não ficaria muito amigável, pois eu teria que especificar o objeto esperado em todas as classes e métodos :/

Comment: @regmoraes como assim *especificar o objeto esperado em todas as classes e métodos*? Você tratar como genérico no seu tipo abstrato, apenas o tipo concreto saberá a "entidade" concreta, por exemplo `MeuCliente`. Ao usar os gerenciados, caso a referência seja para a abstrata informe o tipo, senão nem precisa. Irei atualizar com isto para ver se resolve mais algum ponto

Comment: quando eu disse _especificar o objeto esperado em todas as classes e métodos_ , quis dizer que o desenvolvedor terá que escrever `<MeuCliente>` em vários locais ( na classe `MeuGerenciador`, `AbstractGerenciador`). Mas não creio que isso seja um grande "problema", infelizmente é o preço que se paga por fornecer flexibilidade

Comment: @regmoraes na verdade não é problema mesmo, caso já tenha usado *frameworks* de mercado, como spring, verá que eles usam muito isto e precisamos informar o tipo concreto. Até mesmo a API java, veja como exemplo as coleções em que precisamos informar, tanto quando usamos ou quando criamos uma implementação nova para, por exemplo, `List<E>`, que é um *raw type* =)